# I want to add 'show more comments..' button in my odoo | openerp module

Tags: python, python-2.7, odoo, openerp-8

I am working in one of the odoo | openerp module. However in my module **comments** section displays all the comments on page. So i wanted to add **show more comment button**.

Here is my **view** content:

```
<button class="btn mt8 oe_button">Show more...</button>
```

My **model: py** file

```
class Comment(models.Model):

_name = 'page.comment'
_comments_per_list = 10
```

relevant comment field in my model is:

```
website_message_ids = fields.One2many(
    'mail.message', 'res_id',
    domain=lambda self: [('model', '=', self._name), ('type', '=', 'comment')],
    string='Website Messages', help="Website communication history")
```

and relevant **method** is :

```
@api.multi
def get_comment_detail(self):
    try:
        comments = self.website_message_ids
        values.update({
            'channel': self.channel_id,
            'user': user,
            'comments': comments,
        })
        return values
```

Brief Description:

If a page gets N number of comments than it shows all of them by default.
But I want to control my flow under "show more comments". So, how can it be done within my model.py, I don't know how to deal with it.

On each click, count of 10 comment should be load.

Thanks for Any Help | suggestions in advance

Comment: can you provide controller part?

Comment: It may happen you pass 10 comments in your dictionary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$('.load_comments').on('click', function () {

openerp.jsonRpc("/slides/expand_comment", + $(this).attr('slide-id'), 'call', {
    'values': comments,
}).then(function (data) {
        $(data.target).closest('.list_comment').html($('<div class="media"</div>'));
        // slides: data
});
```

});

try above jsonrpc method